# String formatting questions

Tags: regex

Replacement Array is an array of elements.

Format String contains conversion specifier %s, followed by optional index specifier [1], followed by optional length specifier :3.

Format String: %s[1]:3

```
%s is conversion specifier - mark the starting of conversion string
[1] is index specifier - corresponding index of Replacement Array
:3 is length specifier - number of characters to be taken from string
```

The replacement works as follows:
Example:

```
Replacement Array: Smart site India comparison Best

Format String: %sprix is the %s[4] online %s[3]:6 shopping %s:9 in %s

Output: Smartprix is the Best online compar shopping site in India.

If no index specifier is present with conversion specifier %s, Index 0, 1, 2, 3... are assigned to all in sequence from left to right.
    In above example %sprix is %s[0]prix; %s:9 is %s[1]:9 and so on.
The specifier string is replaced by element of Replacement Array denoted by index specifier. If no element is found the specifier is not replaced.
    In above example %s[4] is replaced by element at 4th index of the Replacement Array "Best". %sprix is replaced by Smartprix and so on.
%s[3]:6 is replaced by 'first 6 characters' of the element at 3rd index of the Replacement Array, i.e., "compar".
If the 'length specifier' is not present or is greater than length of the element then use whole string.
    %s:9 is replaced by site, %s[4] is replaced by Best.
For any error case, specifier is not replaced.
```

Input:

There will be 2 lines in the input.

```
1st line contains space separated elements of Replacement Array
2nd line is Format String
```

Output:

```
Formatted String
```

Example 1:

Input:

Smart site India comparison Best
%sprix is the %s[4] online %s[3]:6 shopping %s:9 in %s.

Output:

Smartprix is the Best online compar shopping site in India.

Example 2:

Input:

India boom startup up hub
%s %s[is] a %sing %s:5%s:5 %s[4]. And %s[6] are:4 of %s[-1].

Output:

India %s[is] a booming startup hub. And %s[6] are:4 of %s[-1].

Comment: What does this have to do with the `facebook` tag? Please tag appropriately. And I can’t see any actual question here either.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works for all test cases

```
package com.test.formatStrings;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FormatStrings {
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
{
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    String input_elements;
    String replacement;
    StringBuilder input_string=new StringBuilder();
    //String output;
    int lastindex1=0, count=0, lastindex2=0;
    ArrayList<String> arrayElements= new ArrayList<String>();

    System.out.println("Enter the array of elements");
    input_elements= sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println(input_elements);

    for(String str: input_elements.split(" "))
    {
        arrayElements.add(str);
    }



    System.out.println("Enter the input String");
    input_string.append(sc.nextLine());
    int length=input_string.length();
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        if(input_string.charAt(i)=='%')
        {
            int first_index=i;
            if(input_string.charAt(i+1)=='s')
            {       
                    if(i+2<input_string.length() && input_string.charAt(i+2)=='[')
                    {
                        if(Character.isLetter(input_string.charAt(i+3))!=true && Character.getNumericValue(input_string.charAt(i+3))>-1)
                        {
                            int ArrayList_firstIndex=Character.getNumericValue(input_string.charAt(i+3));
                            if(input_string.charAt(i+4)==']')
                            {
                                if(input_string.charAt(i+5)==':')
                                {
                                    if(Character.isLetter(input_string.charAt(i+6))!=true && Character.getNumericValue(input_string.charAt(i+6))>-1)
                                    {
                                        int ArrayList_lastIndex=Character.getNumericValue(input_string.charAt(i+6));
                                        replacement=arrayElements.get(ArrayList_firstIndex).substring(0, ArrayList_lastIndex);

                                        int last_index=i+6;
                                        input_string.replace(first_index,last_index+1 , replacement);
                                        length=input_string.length();
                                        i=0;
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if(ArrayList_firstIndex>arrayElements.size())
                                    {
                                        continue;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        replacement=arrayElements.get(ArrayList_firstIndex);
                                        input_string.replace(first_index, first_index+5, replacement);
                                        length=input_string.length();
                                        i=0;
                                    }
                                }
                            }   
                        }
                    }
                    else if(i+2<input_string.length() && input_string.charAt(i+2)==':')
                    {
                        if(Character.isLetter(input_string.charAt(i+3))!=true && Character.getNumericValue(input_string.charAt(i+3))>-1)
                        {
                            int ArrayList_lastIndex=Character.getNumericValue(input_string.charAt(i+3));
                            if(ArrayList_lastIndex>arrayElements.get(count).length())
                            {
                                replacement=arrayElements.get(count);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                replacement=arrayElements.get(count).substring(0, ArrayList_lastIndex);
                            }
                            count++;
                            input_string.replace(first_index,first_index+4 , replacement);
                            length=input_string.length();
                            i=0;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        replacement=arrayElements.get(count);
                        count++;

                        input_string.replace(first_index,first_index+2,replacement);
                        length=input_string.length();
                        i=0;
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }

        System.out.println(input_string);
        sc.close();
    }

}
```